# How to loop bootstrap columns accordingly?

Tags: html, css, laravel

In the loop there comes two types of file. One is Half and other one is full. if the iteration type is half then i want that data to display in (col-lg-4 col-md-6). if the iteration type is full then i want that data to display in  (col-lg-8 col-md-12).

So, now the problem is when the iteration comes twice or thrice or even more consecutively then it displays vertically while looping because of col-lg-8 that doesn't fit in a single row and makes remaining space (col-lg-4 col-md-6) blank.

Now what i want to achieve is if the iteration type full comes consecutively then i want to fill remaining space with iteration type half. so that no blank space will be wasted and doesn't look blank.

My code

```
@foreach($newEvent as $event)
   <div class="row">
       @if($event->type == "half")
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
          <div class="card">
               //images and information
           </div>
         </div>  
       @else 
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12">
           <div class="card">
              //images and information
            </div>
        </div>
       @endif
   </div>
@endforeach
```

[image: Problem is in this picture]

Comment: What exacly do you want to fill the remaining space with? do you want the `col-lg-8` to become `col-lg-12` when the next one is also large??

Comment: @NicoShultz i want to fill remaining space with data that is half

Comment: but with what data? is it static data?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your code with the following:

```php
@php
    $events = $newEvent->sortBy('type');
@endphp
@foreach($events as $event)
   <div class="row">
       @if($event->type == "half")
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
          <div class="card">
               //images and information
           </div>
         </div>  
       @else 
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12">
           <div class="card">
              //images and information
            </div>
        </div>
       @endif
   </div>
@endforeach
```